# How to avoid sudo?

Tags: mount, sudo, filesystem, read-only

I am in folder `/datadrive/` which is the mount point of `/dev/sdc1` (in `/etc/fstab` I have `/dev/sdc1    /datadrive   ext4   defaults,nofail   1   2`) and whenever I try to make any operation in this folder (e.g. `mv`, `cp`, `touch`...) the root privilege is required (`sudo`). I guess this is because the file system is "read-only" (sorry for my ignorance, but I am not sure about that).

Since that I am going to execute many scripts, I would like to convert the file system here in what I guess is called "read/write", so that `sudo` is not anymore required (correct me if I'm wrong).

I already tried with `sudo mount -o remount,rw '/datadrive/'` without any effects. Do you have any idea so on how to remove the `sudo` requirement?

**EDIT**

With `ls -l` I get:

```
total 52
drwxr-xr-x 10 1002 1002  4096 Feb 22 15:53 ./
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root  4096 Feb 22 16:13 ../
drwxrwxr-x  5 1002 1002  4096 Feb 22 16:04 NGS-SparkGATK/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Feb 22 15:36 delete/
drwx--x--x 14 root root  4096 Feb 22 16:13 docker_var/
drwxrwxr-x  9 1002 1002  4096 Jan 22 15:18 fastq/
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root  4096 Feb 22 15:54 libraries/
drwx------  2 root root 16384 Sep 25 13:23 lost+found/
drwxrwxr-x  4 1002 1002  4096 Nov 14 11:37 reference/
drwxrwxrwt 16 root root  4096 Feb 21 12:53 tmp/
```

Comment: Can you edit and add the output to the following command ? `ls -l /datadrive` It seems to be a permission issue.

Comment: The requirement of sudo is not related to whether the device is mounted read/write or not. However, `/dev/sdc` is the primary device (not the partition, which would be `/dev/sdc1` for example), and it's the partition which gets mounted at another location. Given your mount command example with `/datadrive/` I presume that is the actual mount path? Please [edit] your question and explain which file system the partition is. Likely you mounted as root without setting appropriate permissions options when mounting.

Comment: Updated, if I didn't answer correctly to your questions, ask me please!

Comment: Ask the system how `/datadrive` is mounted: `grep /datadrive  /proc/mounts`

Comment: @waltinator `/dev/sdc /datadrive ext4 rw,relatime,stripe=32748,data=ordered 0 0` seems to be Read/Write, so the problem is not in file system type, it must be something else...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see from your `ls -l` output, the files are owned by user `root` and group `root`, or the unknown uid/gid `1002`, and are not world writable.

You can change the owner to your current user, using the `chown` command,  for all the files and directories on the partition. Use `man chown` for documentation on how to use the command.

Comment: thanks man! It was necessary to use `chown -R user /datadrive/`, where "user" is the name of the user who logged to the VM. Feel free to report the command in your answer, to help next users :)

Answer (score 0):

From `man mount`:

```
  defaults
          Use the default options: rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async.
```

And

```
   The non-superuser mounts.
          Normally, only the superuser can mount filesystems.  However, when fstab contains the user option on a line, anybody can mount the corresponding filesystem.

          Thus, given a line

                 /dev/cdrom  /cd  iso9660  ro,user,noauto,unhide

          any user can mount the iso9660 filesystem found on an inserted CDROM using the command

                 mount /dev/cdrom

          or

                 mount /cd

          For more details, see fstab(5).
```

Replace the `defaults` keyword in the `/datadrive` `/etc/fstab` entry with `rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,user,async`. Read `man mount` again and consider changing to `...nosuid,nodev,noexec...`

Comment: thanks for your answer, anyway now the line is /etc/fstab is `/dev/sdc    /datadrive   ext4   rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,user,async,nofail   1   2`, but even after rebooting I still have to use `sudo` for example, for create a file (`sudo touch example.txt`). Moreover in another VM I have the same parameters used in the /etc/fstab's line, so I guess the problem is not here